# How to redirect to page in SvelteKit?

Tags: redirect, svelte, sveltekit

I have a page with content rendered from a SvelteKit store. If the store is invalid, a user needs  do be redirected to the homepage. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to redirect a user even without checking any conditions, so let's focus on a simpler question: **how to always redirect from somepage to homepage?**

I have tried the following, none of this works for me:

- Using `<script context="module">` before script tag on the page as follows:

```
<script context="module">
    export async function load() {
        return {
            status: 302,
            redirect: "/"
        };
    }
</script>
```

- Using PageLoad in +page.js file:

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export function load() {
    return {
        status: 302,
        redirect: '/'
    };
}
```

When I use the code mentioned above, the website works as if nothing was changed, I get no errors, but the redirection does not happen. If I get to the page unexpectedly (type it's address in the search bar, the store is not ready), I get redirected to the error page, because an error happens (which I want to prevent by homepage redirection). If I get to the page expectedly (the store is fine), the page gets rendered normally, no redirect happens.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

See [the SvelteKit Redirect docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#redirects).

```js
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
 
export function load() {
  // ...
  redirect(302, '/'); // needs `throw` in v1
}
```

On the page one would use [`goto`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#%24app-navigation-goto).

Comment: Yes but what if I want to do it outside of the load function? Eg, in a `+page.svelte` file

Comment: Note, for sveltekit 2.0 you can just use `redirect(302, '/');`, no need to throw anything anymore.

Answer (score 16):

Based on the documentation page you would use [goto(theurl)](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#%24app-navigation-goto). Example:

```js
import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
// ...Your other imports
    
goto('/redirectpage');
```

Or if you prefer using native approach, then in file **.svelte** you would do this,

If you are **not using** SSR then this:

```js
window.location.href = '/redirectpage';
```

Or if you are **using** SSR then this:

```js
import { browser } from '$app/environment';
// ...Your other imports
    
if (browser) { // to prevent error window is not defined, because it's SSR
    window.location.href = '/redirectpage';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To do it on the server, you put it in `+page.server.ts`:

```
// src/routes/page-to-redirect/+page.server.ts

import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export function load() {
    throw redirect(302, '/redirect-to-this-url');
}
```

Comment: Note, for sveltekit 2.0 you can just use `redirect(302, '/');`, no need to throw anything anymore.