# How to return back to the same page after login redirect in Svelte?

Tags: sveltekit

I am referring to [How to redirect to page in SvelteKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74805197/how-to-redirect-to-page-in-sveltekit) and add another question:

I want to redirect to /login every time I open a page in my app (a page that requires authenticated user, that is). I plan to use the redirect in `load()` function in `+layout.ts` so that the same pattern is applied in every page.

My question: how can I tell the login page where to redirect after successful login? Can I use Referer header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many techniques you can use for this.

Perhaps, the simplest one would be to use a query string. For example, if you call your login like this:

```
/login?returnTo=<url>
```

You then need to read this parameter and redirect the user back. Bear in mind that this can cause some undesirable issues like someone forging a malicious URL. For this reason, you will need to sanitise and ensure the URL is valid before redirecting the user. Likewise, this value could be dropped so it is good to have a fallback URL.

Similar techniques are to use local and session storage (in case you stay in the browser when you do the redirect).

If you submit a form for the login, you can use a hidden input field to hold your return URL which you can then retrieve as part of the form data in the server.

Finally, a different approach is to use a cookie to communicate with the server. This has the advantage of allowing you to use HttpOnly cookies (if you don't need browser access) so that the client can't alter the value (I would still validate it, tho). As a matter of fact, I'm using this technique in a project I'm working on right now.

If the Referer header is set, you can very well use it but you will need server assistance as I don't think you will be able to grab it in the client.

Comment: Thank you and I need to learn a bit more about cookies :)