# How can I navigate pragmatically in sveltekit?

Tags: navigation, svelte, sveltekit, navigator

Using sveltekit, after authenticating a user, how can I redirect to another internal page (in this case, simply on '/')?
I've already tried goto() and redirect(), but the first gives a usage error on the server (Cannot call goto(...) on the server, when I use it on the client side), while the second, just prints the error and doesn't redirect.
To understand this, I would simply need something like nuxt's navigateTo().

Comment: Are you looking for [goto](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto) from [$app/navigation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation)

Comment: Show your code. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74805197/546730).

Comment: Yes, I tried goto from $app/navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved thanks to H.B.'s comment that linked this post to me: [How to redirect to page in SvelteKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74805197/546730).

So I used:

```
import { browser } from '$app/environment';
// ...Your other imports

if (browser) { // to prevent error window is not defined, because it's SSR
    window.location.href = '/redirectpage';
}
```

The problem now is that window.location reloads the whole page. So It's better use goto() that instructs the sveltekit router to do a client side navigation instead.

```
goto('/redirectpage');
```

This can also help with other client side things like writing localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Using [redirect](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#sveltejs-kit-redirect) would be the correct way to accomplish this. Are you sure you're not catching the thrown redirect?

Comment: yes, maybe because I'm using it on client and not on server side.. But I need it on client.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).